# What is different about the Jenkins Build environment than regular?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jenkins

I have a mac pro set up, and whenever i run a gradle command for a Google App Engine java project:

`./gradlew run -DmainClassName=MyScript`

It runs just fine.

however, whenever I run the exact same command on Jenkins, it fails, saying missing symbols on some google API:

`com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.MapSpecification.Builder.build();`

What is happening?

(the gradle command is trying to run a remote script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins runs as a `jenkins` user. Probably you have something in your user `path` that you don't have in `jenkins`'s `path`

Comment: yeah i had to export my crap all over again last night from bash into my jenkins env. it worked.